# Errors in the resulted columns after merging with Pivot_Table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, multiple-columns

after applying ***Pivot_Table*** on a recently merged DataFrame ,  i realised that the columns that i got were not what i was expecting.

Basically , rather than getting this output :

```
 df4.Ammonia:

 NAN
 NAN
 NAN
 .
 .
```

I got this output:

```
 df4.Ammonia:

 Time
 2013-11-01 00:00:00   NaN
 2013-11-01 01:00:00   NaN
 2013-11-01 02:00:00   NaN 
 .
 .
```

the column index seems to appear every and each time i inspect a column !!

Here's My code:

```
Mi_Pollution['Measurement'] = Mi_Pollution['Measurement'].astype(float)
Mi_Pollution['Sensor_ID'] = Mi_Pollution['Sensor_ID'].astype(float)
Mi_Pollution['Time']=list(Mi_Pollution.index)
Mi_Pollution.reset_index()
df3 = Mi_Pollution.merge(Pollutants, on='Sensor_ID', how='left')
```

And Than:

```
df4 = df3.pivot_table(index=['Time'],values='Measurement',columns='Sensor_Type')
```

Any Suggestion Would be Much Appreciated , Thank U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected,you get `Datetimeindex`, because column after parameter `index` in `pivot_table` create index of returned `DataFrame` - here `time` column created `DatetimeIndex`.

Check it by:

```
print (df4.index)
```

If need default index use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for convert DattimeIndex to new column and replace it by `RangeIndex` and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for remove column name (`Time` string):

```
df4 = df4.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank u for everything